# How to access to a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a stupid pb, but I don't find any topics about it. I'm trying to make a button add which is a fixed partial view. But when i'm passing the css position:fixed, the element is rendering in the background, and I can't access it. 
So is there another way to do this ?

My code :

(Layout/application)

```
<%= render "partials/add" %>
<%= yield %>
```

(partials/add)

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div class="add_task_layout">
    +
  </div>
<%end%>
```

(css)

```
.add_task_layout{
  position: fixed;
  border: none;
  height:60px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom:5%;
  right:5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  border-radius:50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #5CC551;
  pointer-events: none; 
  font-weight:bold;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  &:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

This button should appear on all my pages on the First layer displayed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead of included your partials could you included the rendered markup? You problem is likely related to a stacking issue. Try using `z-index` to elevate it above the other elements.

Comment: Hi @hungerstar, thanks for your answer. I already try your solution, and it's working for the displaying, but I still can't access to the element. It's just changing the displaying order

Comment: Well, I don't know how/where you applied anything so I have no idea why you cannot access the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.add_task_layout{ 
z-index: 99;
...
}
```

try with z-index property

Comment: Hi @Falkwn, thanks for your answer. I already try your solution, and it's working for the displaying, but I still can't access to the element. It's just changing the displaying order

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue totally then. You could try to switch the class with the z-index to the link_to : <%= link_to root_path, class: 'yourclass' do %>

Comment: Oh, ok I didn't understand that I have to pass the params to the link_to. so I pass the params position:fixed and z-index to the link_to and I remove it from the div. Thanks @Falkwn, it's much better like this, have a good day bro